# Django - Add extra clause for login with AbstractUser inheritance

Tags: python, django, authentication, abstractuser

I have the following model:

`employee.py`

```
class Employee(auth_models.AbstractUser, MetadataModel):
    user = models.CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My `settings.py` references to `Employee` model for authentication:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.Person'
```

By default, the user can only log in with the `AbstractUser` model when `is_active=True`. How can I change this condition so that the authentication is: `is_active==True` and `is_deleted==False` preserving the inheritance on `AbstractUser` in `Employee`?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) for that, like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

class MyBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        # Check the username/password and return a user.
        try:
            user = Employee.objects.get(username=username, is_active=True,is_deleted=False)
            if check_password(password, user.password):
                  return user
         except Employee.DoesNotExist():
             return None
         return None
```

Then add this new backend in your `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =  ['yourapp.auth_backend.MyBackend']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a quite interesting approach. I am having an additional issue: when including the `AUTHENTIFICATION_BACKENDS` variable, I have included traces and my backend is never reached when authentificating. I suspect that the path is not being held correctly. My path is as follows: `src/core/backends/auth_backend.py` - MyBackend and in `settings.py` I have tried with several combinations, the last one is as follows: `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =  ['core.backends.auth_backend.MyBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']`. Is this correct?

Comment: There was one mistake from my side, I added additional argument `request`, which was not necessary. I have removed it, so can you try the updated answer?

Comment: Hi, I've just tried but it happens the same thing, it does not enter in `MyBackend`

Comment: What happens if you remove the ModelBackend? Also how are you calling the authentication method?